# Tomcat 8.5.X: Migrate Valve javacode from Tomcat 7

Tags: java, migration, tomcat7, tomcat8

I need to migrate one of our custom Valve code from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8.5:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.catalina.Container;
import org.apache.catalina.Manager;
import org.apache.catalina.Session;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;

public class SessionManagerValve extends ValveBase {

    @Override
    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
      // ...
    }

    public HttpSession findSession(String id, boolean updateLastAccessTime) {
        try {
            Container container = getContainer();

            // works with Tomcat 7.x, but not with Tomcat 8.5 anymore...
            Manager man = container.getManager();

            Session sess = man.findSession(id);
            return sess.getSession();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           return null;
       } 
    }
}
```

The `Container` interface does not provide the `getManager()` method anymore. According to the Tomcat migration guide, accessing the `Manager` has moved from `Container`to `Context`.

Can anybody give me a hint how to access the `Manager` from within the `ValveBase`object?

Thanks in advance,
     Rainer

**EDIT**: The Context configuration is - as correctly noted in the answer -

```
<Context path="" ...>
    <Valve className="SessionManagerValve" />
</Context>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Valve` is at the `Context` level (it would have to be for the code above to work) then you need:

```
((Context) getContainer()).getManager();
```

Comment: Correct, getContainer() gives me an instance of org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext in this case. Thank you!